# Variable dimensional integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax

I need to `Integrate` a function, but let the number of dimensions vary.

```
Integrate[Product[Exp[-( t[[i]] )^2], {i,1,4}], options]
```

with

```
t = {u,v,x,y}
```

and

```
options = {#,-Infinity,Infinity}&/@{u,v,x,y}
```

but the double braces on options doesn't allow this to work. I get this for options:

> {{u, -Infinity, Infinity}, {v, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x,
>   -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}}

If I want a general list of variables, can these be added as variables into integrate, with the corresponding limits? I need a variable dimension, simply taken from the length of a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence) to eliminate a set of brackets:

```
t = {u, v, x, y};
Integrate[
    Product[
        Exp[-( t[[i]] )^2],
        {i,1,4}
    ],
    Sequence @@ ({#,-Infinity,Infinity}&/@t)
]
```

> π^2

However, it is simpler to use a [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) specification instead:

```
Integrate[Exp[-p.p], p ∈ FullRegion[4]]
```

> π^2

Comment: Thank you very much. Is `p` a vector, hence FullRegion[4]?

Comment: @AlexanderKartun-Giles Yes, `p` is a symbolic vector.

Comment: Ok I will look that up. Thank you.